# Newton-Raphson convergence for function $f(\gamma)$ with $\gamma \geq0$ constraint.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, newton-raphson

I am reading an (engineering) paper that in the part of their solution, They propose a 2-step iterative solution based on *Newton-Raphson* method for concave function $f$ as below :

1.$\gamma^{t+1}=\gamma^{t}-[H_f(\gamma^{t})]^{-1}\nabla_f(\gamma^{t})$

2.Set the elements of $\gamma$ vector with value less than *zero* to *zero*.

Although I am not a mathematician but I am wondering if this method actually converges or at least is expected to converge. I went through the litreture a little but actually I didn't find this way of solving elsewhere.

I want to know does(and why) this (indulgent?) way of solving actually works in practice?

Comment: There are basically two cases to think about. First there's the case where the global maximum is in the constraint region. In this case you see the ordinary Newton's method behavior: you generally don't have convergence if you start too far away. If you do start far away, then the situation is complicated, even without the constraint issue.

Comment: The more troubling case to me is when the global maximum is *not* in the constraint region. For a trivial example, you could be maximizing $-(x+1)^2$ for $x \geq 0$. Here the maximum is on the boundary. I don't quite see how this method would detect that it should stop on the boundary, in a problem where that is the case.

Comment: This is just a projected Newton method. Nothing wrong with it whatsoever, although without any sort of step size control on step 1, it might be a bit delicate to prove convergence.

Comment: You'll find far more literature about projected *gradient* methods, so I would encourage you to look there. But once you understand those, it won't be hard to see why this will work, too.